# nginx rewrite with php-fpm

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I have debian server with nginx + php-fpm on board.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.0.15

PHP 5.3.10-1~dotdeb.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb  3 2012 00:21:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH
```

this server is for facebook applications. server will host several applications, each application has a php file as an entry point, like history.php, collection.php etc.

the question is how to change server config in order to process the URIs like this

```
domain.com/facebook/history/
```

processes like

```
domain.com/facebook/history.php
```

but browser url stays the same.

here is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    keepalive_timeout       70;
    server_name             domain.com;
    root                    /var/www/public;
    index                   index.php index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            access_log        off;
            expires           1d;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/public$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    ## There is not apache on server but still
    ## Disable viewing .htaccess & .htpassword
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've catched all other locations with nginx rules and add this to `location /`

```
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/$ /$1/$2.php last;
```

Comment: this is a straightforward solution, I appreciate your help, but I want to make a universal rule for all pages like that. Aiming no config changes in future.

Comment: Check now, please.

Comment: Well, it's almost ok!
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/$ /$1/$2.php last;
leading slash is required

Comment: there is a new feature buy now:

it somehow conflicts with try_files...
I hasn't understood the exact misbehavior by the moment...

Comment: After answering to this question to yourself you can answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122640/nginx-rewrite-rule-try-files-not-working-together) question:) I'd suggest you to try to move `try_files` and `rewrite` around, like moving `rewrite` into `location /` or coping `try_files` outside.